# mysql query - arranging rows by field and counting id x place

Tags: mysql

```
id field
1  100
2  80
3  200
4  230
```

Is it possible to find out the rank of id 2 for example if ordered by field DESC?

In this case the ranks would be:

```
1. #4
2. #3
3. #1
4. #2 (our winner)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you would need.  Note that since MySQL doesn't have a row numbering function, you need to use a variable in its place

```
SET @rank=0;    
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id, field FROM table ORDER BY field DESC
) vw
WHERE vw.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

rank is automatically in that case is created when used `ORDER BY DESC`. id's will keep selected in proper ranking order.

```
SELECT id,field FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I believe this is not such trivial as you think

Comment: ORDER BY clause should be together.

Comment: @SSpoke It wouldn't really be of any use since I need to get the rank of a specific row.